# is it possible to know when an iframe with cross site content has finished an ajax request?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that uses an iframe that is displaying content from another site. That content is basically a wizard, forward/back button etc. The content is refreshed via ajax. I've been trying various things to get the page to scroll back up to the top when the user has hit the next button. The thing that seemed most likely to work was to attach a function to the ajaxSuccess event like so:

```
    $('#eyeFrame').ajaxSuccess(function () {
        alert('Triggered ajaxSuccess handler');
    });
```

But it never fired. It seems like there's nothing I can do to interact with that content inside the iframe or determine if the iframe has kicked off some ajax. Is that correct or is there a way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Look in the javascript console for any network connections.

Comment: @Neal that seems like it would work, but  a quick search leads me to believe the only Net calls I'd be able to see from my JS would be to my domain. Got any links that would show me all network activity from JS?

Comment: @Neal I added this code: `$("#eyeFrame").bind({
                ajaxStart: function () { alert('ajaxStart'); }
            }); ` but it didn't fire when I did some ajax stuff from within the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iframe location belongs to the same domain, you can use $('#eyeFrame').load(function(){/* */});
There are some drawback anyway
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

For another domain I don't know of a solution.

Comment: For another domain there is no solution due to browser security.

Comment: yep. that's what I forgot to say

Comment: however, .load will not trigger when an ajax call from the page inside the iframe is fired. That isn't something that we'll be able to listen for from the parent page.

Comment: You can with [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage), if the browser supports it.

Comment: @topek I've looked at postMessage before, I think I'd need to have control over the content from the other domain to make use of it.